# Javascript math check

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to build a ROMI (return on marketing investment calculator) in javascript, and I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm attempting to take a value from a form, pass it to "leadGeneration" then manipulate it using the formula below, then have the output "msRomi" displayed in a text box. I'd like to add a disclaimer that I am not a web developer, I am a marketing analyst, so I apologize for any gratuitous errors or novice mistakes. I've looked around, and based on resources from this site and several tutorial sites this code should be valid (it just doesn't happen to be) could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or how to fix it?

```
var leadGeneration = $("leadGeneration");
var conversionTools = $("conversionTools");
var brandRecognition = $("brandRecognition");
var loyalityBuilding = $("loyalityBuilding");
var marketingSpending = $("marketingSpending");


var deltaLg = 375;
var deltaCt = 75;
var deltaBr = 93.75;
var deltaLb = 56.25;
var totalPms = 100000;

var msPercent = parseFloat(marketingSpending) / parseFloat(totalPms);

var lgromi= (((msPercent * (leadGeneration)) * parseFloat(deltaLg) * (2280) / ((parseFloat(msPercent) * (parseFloat(leadGeneration)))
var ctRomi= ((msPercent) * (conversionTools)) * parseFloat(deltaCt) * (2280) / ((parseFloat(msPercent) * (parseFloat(leadGeneration)))
var brRomi= ((msPercent) * (brandRecognition)) * parseFloat(deltaBr) * (2280) / ((parseFloat(msPercent) * (parseFloat(leadGeneration)))
var lbRomi= ((msPercent) * (loyalityBuilding)) * parseFloat(deltaLb) * (2280) / ((parseFloat(msPercent) * (parseFloat(leadGeneration)))

var msRomi= parseFloat(lgRomi) + parseFloat(ctRomi) + parseFloat(brRomi) + parseFloat(lbRomi)
```

HTML

```
<div class="marketingSpending" style="align: center">Marketing Spending:</div>
<input type="range" name="marketingSpending" min="5000" max="100000" step="1000" style="width: 70px">
</div>


<div class="inputForm" id="calcValues" style="align: right">
<form id="romiForm">

<div class="percentName" style="align: left">Lead Generation:</div>
<form action="" class="percentSelection">
<select name="leadGeneration" id="leadGeneration">
<option value="10" selected>10%</option>
<option value="20">20%</option>
<option value="30">30%</option>
<option value="40">40%</option>
<option value="50">50%</option>
<option value="60">60%</option>
<option value="70">70%</option>
<option value="80">80%</option>
<option value="90">90%</option>
<option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="percentName" style="align: right">Conversion Tools:</div>
<form action="" class="percentSelection">
<select name="conversionTools" id="conversionTools">
<option value="10" selected>10%</option>
<option value="20">20%</option>
<option value="30">30%</option>
<option value="40">40%</option>
<option value="50">50%</option>
<option value="60">60%</option>
<option value="70">70%</option>
<option value="80">80%</option>
<option value="90">90%</option>
<option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="percentName">Brand Recognition:</div>
<form action="" class="percentSelection">
<select name="brandRecognition" id="brandRecognition">
<option value="10" selected>10%</option>
<option value="20">20%</option>
<option value="30">30%</option>
<option value="40">40%</option>
<option value="50">50%</option>
<option value="60">60%</option>
<option value="70">70%</option>
<option value="80">80%</option>
<option value="90">90%</option>
<option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="percentName">Customer Loyalty:</div>
<form action="" class="percentSelection">
<select name="customerLoyalty" id="customerLoyalty">
<option value="10" selected>10%</option>
<option value="20">20%</option>
<option value="30">30%</option>
<option value="40">40%</option>
<option value="50">50%</option>
<option value="60">60%</option>
<option value="70">70%</option>
<option value="80">80%</option>
<option value="90">90%</option>
<option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
</form>


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: can we see the html as well?

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: `$("leadGeneration")` and the others are not numerical values, but jQuery objects (unless `$` is not jQuery but a custom function?). You have to extract the values from it with `.val()` (if form inputs) or `.html()` (if other html element).

Comment: On a similar note, you're probably trying to grab them by ID so you're going to need a `#` in your jQuery selector so it would look something like `$("#leadGeneration")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your elements have to be selected by `id` or by `class`.  I'm not sure which it will need to be without looking at your HTML, but I'll guess `id`:

```
var leadGeneration = $("#leadGeneration"); ...
```

Notice the `#` denoting the element's `id` attribute. Also, @bfavaretto's comment is correct, that these jQuery objects we're creating contain a lot more than the value of their content, so we can't do regular math on them. An example of extracting a value from these objects would be like:

```
var leadGenerationVal = leadGeneration.val()
```

Or we could extract the value on the same line as we create the jQuery object, if you don't want to do anything else with the object on the page:

```
var leadGeneration = $("#leadGeneration").val();
```

With the line of code above as an example, you should be able to get the rest of your script to work.

Comment: So I would use var leadGeneration = $("#leadGeneration").val(); to initialize the variable leadGeneration then I would use leadGeneration in my math formula? i.e. leadGeneration * msPercent would give me the product? and Javascript understands the parentheses? A question about passing values from HTML forms, I would only have to assign the form an id then pass that id to Javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by understanding the parentheses, but yes, if you declare leadGeneration as `$("#leadGeneration").val()`, then you can perform math operations with it. The form id doesn't matter, it's the id of the `select` element that jQuery is accessing.